# Criando URL Amigável não sei como fazer

Tags: php, htaccess

Tenho um site e na index.php e onde se faz o cadastro e login.
Assistir algumas vídeos aulas porem todas elas fazer a explicação usando a index como exemplo para que possa pegar a url e trabalha-la com o php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Tenho que tirar todo conteudo do index e colocar em um novo arquivo para que eu possa deixar o index so para verificaçoes de url????????

outra duvida e que se eu não quizer fazer da maneira acima posso optar por ficar reescrevendo o que o usuario digita e para onde ele vai somente com o htaccess? e isso mesmo? ou tem outra forma?

exemplo:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^login(.*)$ login.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendi a sua pergunta muito bem, mas.

1 - crie um arquivo .htaccess.

2 - Não mecha na index com htaccess já que é a página principal.

3 - pra modificar as URL faça o seguinte.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^Nome-da-pagina-que-vc-quer?$ Nome-da-pagina-que-vc-quer-mudar.php[QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```